# Angular 5 routerLink doesn't work correctly

Tags: angular, routerlink

There are one module which contains all components and one route module.

The routing module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { UserComponent } from './user/user.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
import { AdminDishesComponent } from './admin/adminDishes/adminDishes.component';
import { AdminCategoriesComponent } from './admin/adminCategories/adminCategories.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'user'
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: UserComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dishes',
        component: AdminDishesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'categories',
        component: AdminCategoriesComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})

export class RoutingModule { }
```

The root component:

```
<a routerLink="/admin">Admin control panel</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The admin component:

```
<ul id="leftMenu">
  <li><a routerLink="/dishes">Dishes</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="/categories">Categories</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="adminContent">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

### Please

The links need to be like:

```
http://localhost:4200/admin/categories
```

But Angular give me in the link:

```
http://localhost:4200/categories
```

If I enter the adress that I need myself in address bar everything is working.

Comment: Remove the / from the routerLinks in admin component

Comment: I'd recommend running through https://angular.io/guide/router, particularly on absolute vs. relative links

Comment: and  also maintain 1 router-outlet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So this is a simple mistake..

There a two types of paths in angular 
**relative paths** and **absolute paths**

so an **absolute path** looks like this `/admin/categories` notice the `/` at the beginning that means it will start the path from the root path which is specified in your index.html as `<base href="/">`

now a **relative path** `categories` will just add that to the path you are currently on so if you on `http://localhost:4200/admin` and you click on a `routerLink` with `categories` you will go to `http://localhost:4200/admin/categories` which is what you are trying to achieve here.

so just remove the `/` like so... `<a routerLink="dishes">dishes</a>`

or if you like you could use an absolute path.. `<a routerLink="/admin/dishes">dishes</a>`

Comment: I understood. Thank you!